# Opening PDF file of multiple pages inside iframe on iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe, mobile

Opening PDF file of multiple pages inside `iframe` on iOS browsers

**Expected:** on desktop browsers, it opens/loads **all the pages** of the PDF

**Problem:** on iOS browsers, it opens/loads **only the fist page** of the PDF.

example: https://angular-iframe-mobile.stackblitz.io

PDF sample used: https://gahp.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/sample.pdf